# A exclamatory sentence with a question mark

Tags: sentence-construction, usage

What time is it? [if asked to know about the time, is a direct question]

What time it is! [an exclamatory sentence]

What time is it? [if asked to draw the addressee's attention, is a rhetorical question]

What time it is? [if said to show surprise, is a declarative question]

Can a sentence with an interrogative structure with a question mark at the end be an expression of surprise?

> To what extent can you bear it?

Comment: These examples don't really work, and I don't think anybody would use "What is the time?" in these contexts.  If you are looking for a question form which could be used this way then perhaps "Would you look at the time?".  This is a common expression used in the UK to mean something like "I didn't realise what time it was, I really have to go now".

Comment: Please see what my question is: Can a sentence with an interrogative structure with a question mark at the end be an expression of surprise?
I just want to know about this.

Comment: Some can, but not "What is the time?". Usually these are stock phrases/expression, such as "Would you believe it?", "How cool is that?", "What the hell is he doing now?", etc - you can't just do this with any question. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: @BillyKerr - I'm sure I've heard people ask "What is the time?" But, xeesid, we don't use "What time it is!" as an exclamation - more likely "Look at the time!"

Comment: What @BillyKerr said. But I wouldn't say it's "correct" to punctuate exclamations in the form of questions with a shebang / shriek / exclamation mark. It's an *acceptable* orthography to most people, but I'm quite certain the vast majority of written instances of exclamatory *Would you believe it?* will use the question mark, not the shebang. If you *always* use a question mark after an utterance framed as a question, you'll never actually be *wrong*, even if some people might make a different choice. (So just do that and you've got a bit less to learn! :)

Comment: @KateBunting, there's nothing wrong with "What is the time?" as a question asking the time. I meant the other uses suggested by the OP, as an exclamation.

Comment: "*What time **it is***" is bad grammar both as an exclamation and as a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a question with a question mark can be used an expression of surprise.

"What time is it" is a better question to use as an exclamation than "To what extent can you bear it", so let's use that first.

Imagine someone has a job interview, and as they look at their phone to check the time, they realize that they're late. They might scream, "*WHAT TIME IS IT?!?*" while still looking at the time on their phone. This is not a question, but an expression of surprise.

As Kate Bunting has pointed out, a more natural version of that question is "How can you bear it?", which can be used as an *exclamatory sentence* (also known as an *exclamative sentence*). Normally, these sentences are *declarative*, like, "What a game that was!", but questions can also work, if the intent is rhetorical.

So yes, someone can scream, "*How can you bear it?!?*" just as an expression of their surprise, not expecting a response.

Answer (score 1):

*To what extent can you bear it?* is not at all idiomatic - *to what extent* is much too formal. We might ask *How can you bear it?*, but that is always a question, even though it may express surprise that the person can tolerate 'it' at all.

Comment: This appears to be a comment on the question itself, rather than an answer to the OP's question, which, as I understand it, is whether sentences with question grammar and formatting can, in general, be used as exclamations, rather than questions.

Comment: @gotube - I meant to imply that they can't - a question is always a question even though it may express surprise.